# How to automatically include PUG mixins in entry page?

Tags: javascript, webpack, pug

Project: Webpack (js, cass, pug). [Repo link](https://github.com/MadGoby/Task-2)
My task is to convert all imports in the project to automatic. For CSS and JS, I followed the recommendations from the official Webpack website and in my case they work fine:

```
function importAll(context) {
  context.keys().map(context);
}

function importContext() {
  importAll((require.context('./../blocks', true, /.scss$|Init.js/)));
}
```

But I have no idea how to implement the same for the Pug includes. At the moment, I manually connect each Mixin:

```
include ../../blocks/block1/block1.pug
include ../../blocks/block2/block2.pug
include ../../blocks/block3/block3.pug

+block1()
+block2()
+block3()
```

Please advise a method by which you can automatically connect all mixins